# How to login to a different user id and execute command?

Tags: shell-script

I am executing below shell script from a different User ID. But everytime I execute this script it worked smoothly upto 'sudo su ${USER_ID}'. And then it stops to execute. Please suggest me how Can I execute whole commands after login to different user by the script.

Below is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATCH_FILE=" "
USER_ID=" "
Grp_ID=" "

sudo mv ${PATCH_FILE} /tmp
sudo chown ${USER_ID}:${Grp_ID} /tmp/${PATCH_FILE}
sudo su ${USER_ID}
cd /tmp
unzip ${PATCH_FILE}
```

Comment: `su` open interactive shell, pass commands you want to execute with `-c`

Comment: Drop the `sudo`s and run the script as `root`

Answer (score 0):

Your script doesn't stop to execute, it does what it is told to do. It starts an interactive shell and that shell waits for input. It does not read the input from the script unless you tell it to do that:

```
sudo su ${USER_ID} << EOF
cd /tmp
unzip ${PATCH_FILE}
EOF
```

Note that `sudo su` is almost always unnecessary.

Note that the example above solves the generic problem, pass lines as stdandard input. It is not necessarily the best solution to your case.